# C# import a structure from C DLL

Tags: c#, c, dll, struct

I have the following C header for two structs:

```
struct CustomerInfo
{
    char* Id;
    char* Name;
    char* Address;
};

struct CustomerList
{
    CustomerInfo* Info;
    CustomerList* Next;
};
```

Which is a simple list.

A function is exported so that the CustomerList is returned (or better the pointer to it)

```
EXPORTC CustomerList* ListCustomer(void* bankPtr)
```

bankPtr is a not a problem here, there is a function which will return it.

Here is how I call the function in C#:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public struct CustomerInfo
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3)]
        public IntPtr Id;
        public IntPtr Name;
        public IntPtr Address;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public unsafe struct CustomerList
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 2)]
        CustomerInfo* Info;
        CustomerList* Next;
    };

    ...

    [DllImport("bank.dll", EntryPoint = "ListCustomer", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private unsafe static extern Customer* _ListCustomer(int bankPtr);
```

Then the function itself:

```
    public unsafe static CustomerList* ListCustomer()
    {
        CustomerList* c = _ListCustomer(Init());

        return c;
    }
```

But the variable `c` has not the fields that I want to access.

What is the error in my doing? Is it possible to pass a struct this way? The functions are C exported, not C++, I found some examples for C++.

**Update**:

I tried accessing it the following after making the changes from NineBerry:

```
public unsafe static CustomerList* ListCustomer()
{
    CustomerList* c = _ListCustomer(Init());
    Console.Write("customer list: " + (int)c);

    string name = new string(c->Info->Name);

    return c;
}
```

Which procudes this error:

```
CS0193  The * or -> operator must be applied to a pointer
```

**Update #2:**

Using NineBerrys approach I got it working somehow, but the pointers seem to point in the wrong directions.

I printed out name, address and id:

```
Name    ???????t??\P???????????
adr     ?????????????2?????????????
Id      ????????????????????????????C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\VCRUNTIME140D.dll

Name    ???????t??N
adr     ?????????????2???????
Id      ???????????????????????▒????????
```

These are the results.

Comment: Thank you, but the compiler does not seem to be ok with it: `Cannot take the address of, get the size of, or declare a pointer to a managed type ('Bank.CustomerInfo')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare the structs like this:

```
 public unsafe struct CustomerInfo
 {
      public sbyte* Id;
      public sbyte* Name;
      public sbyte* Address;
 }

 public unsafe struct CustomerList
 {
      public CustomerInfo* Info;
      public CustomerList* Next;
 };
```

For example, to access the name of the first customer:

```
string name = new string(c->Info->Name);
```

Comment: Thank you, I changed the code, but it does not work unfortunateley.

I updated the calling code in the first post.

Comment: Yes, got VS2015. I copy pasted it again, now it seems to compile without error.

Comment: Updated the opening questions, some char* are pointing in the wrong direction I think.

Comment: I changed char* to sbyte* in CustomerInfo . Please test this. If this doesn't help, test different values for "CallingConvention". Otherwise you need to supply more details on the DLL.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Any hints why sbyte behaves so differently?

Comment: It seems the dll you use still uses Ansi strings. So each character has one byte. Char* in C# always uses unicode strings where each character has four bytes.